# Cannot find symbol variable editText

Tags: android

I am attempting Android Developer's "Building Your First App" project. I have followed the instructions provided accordingly yet I am experiencing the error mentioned above.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user taps the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.**editText**);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Upon clicking "run", the error message above was displayed. While the rest of my values can be resolved, the editText variable remains in RED font (which I placed in bold above). 
According to Android Developer's website, the code block is supposed to look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user taps the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Can someone please explain to me why I am not able to resolve the symbol for editText? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure of these two things:

1. There is an `EditText` element in "activity_main.xml" with `android:id="@+id/editText"`
2. You are importing the right `R` class. The correct one should be `<applicationPackage>.R`

Answer (score 2):

Same happened here.

All you need to do is change in the respective XML file, where it is:

```
 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Edit_Text + **smt else**"
```

To:

```
 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Edit_Text"
```

If you have similar errors, follow the same procediment. I hope that i helped you!

Answer (score 2):

This is my very first android app. I solved this problem as below -

1. Goto activity_main.xml
2. Click on Code on top right corner where you have 3 options - Code | Split | Design
3. Replace

   <EditText

   ```
         android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
   ```

with

<EditText

```
         android:id="@+id/editText"
```

This is it.

Answer (score 1):

That means you have not created resource with id edit_text.
Iniside your XML make sure you have created id

```
  <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"/>
```

if you have created xml with id please check Imported package for R

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Android development, I resolved this issue by following changes

Earlier it was like below in **activity_main.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />
```

replaced with below in **activity_main.xml**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />
```

Just replaced **TextView** with **EditText** and **@+id/textView** with **@+id/editText**.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, too.
There is a `"<EditText..."` entry in activity_main.xml, and somehow mine had editText2 in it, instead of editText.  I just had to rename it back to "editText".

Answer (score 0):

The error because of you insert from **Palette** *TextView* instead of *Plain Text (editText)*